# How to rename system name on Freya

Tags: release-freya

How can I change system name in my freya os. It has some extended text. I want to rename it. I try read some command like the below one, which has no success for me

```
sudo /etc/hostname
sudo /etc/hosts
```

i guess there is simple way to rename it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to execute an texteditor to edit these files.
Example of editors are scratch-text-editor, gedit, nano, vi,... .

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/hostname
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/hosts
```

For the `/etc/hosts` file just make sure their is a entry to your new hostname and delete the old one

```
127.0.1.1       newhostname
127.0.1.1       oldhostname #delete this one
```

Than you just restart your computer.